# WordPress - custom archive page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a custom HTML archive blog page in which I would like to place WordPress posts.  The custom page has several different layouts and therefore looping through the posts is just regenerating the whole page in which I am trying to avoid.  What I am looking to do is loop through each post and then place that post in the relevant archive col.

so post 1 goes into row 1 col 1, post 2 goes into row 2 col 1, post 3 goes into row 2 col 2, post 4 goes into row 2 col 3 and so on...

If this is not possible, is there a way in which I can have one block of code e.g. only the first row and col as below and with each PHP loop iteration the CSS markup changes.  for example on the first iteration, the col is 100% width, on the second iteration, the col is 50% width.

This is quite difficult to explain so hopefully the above makes some sense.

below is an example of the markup.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<!-- ROW 1 -->
<div class="card mt-5 row-card-shadow">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/450x350" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <!-- COL 2 POST-1 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card-block p-3">
                        <h4 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read more..</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <div class="row py-5 row-three-cards">
            <!-- COL 1 POST-2 -->
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card" style="width: auto;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">TEST</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read more..</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <!-- COL 2 POST-3 -->
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card" style="width: auto;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read more..</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <!-- COL 3 POST-4 -->
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card" style="width: auto;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read more..</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>                
        </div>
   <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is there any (mathematical) logic behind which post is supposed to go where, or is that just arbitrary? From your current description I can’t really tell, especially not how it is supposed to continue after the _“and so on..”_

Comment: So the latest post should be at the top of the page and then all the others drop down.  I know you can create a block of code in which a post archieve is created, then on the second loop it finds the next post and repeats the block of code (therefore identical looking archive posts).  What I am looking to achieve is having different looking archieve posts for example one post with a 100% width and then the second with a 50% width.  In other words I am trying to avoid earch archieve entry looking the same

Comment: Well if you just want to format the very first post differently, all you need to know is if you are in the first loop iteration, or not. That is rather trivial to determine using a little flag, such as `$isFirstIteration = true;` set before the loop, and at the end of the loop iteration you set it to false …

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found in WP Beginner, but I am modifying it to your need.

I am new to WordPress development. So, Please verify this on localhost before you use on production.

```
    <?php

    $archieve_post = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

    <?php if ( $archieve_post->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul>
        <?php while ( $archieve_post->have_posts() ) : $archieve_post->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
<div class="card mt-5 row-card-shadow">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-6">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card-block p-3">
                        <h4 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read more..</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you want to split posts to different categories. So you can change your markup that will make some columns that will be defined with some CSS classes (you can set condition that will check if current post is in the category then add CSS class or something like this). If you want to split them outside one Wordpress Loop, you can use Multiple WordPress Loops to make custom template for different categories.

Here is the link for [wordpress loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) documentation. Hope that will help you.